# MvcResult returns application/json;charset=UTF-8

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5, spring-boot-test

This is the first time I'm trying to write Integration Tests with the spring framework test. The controller returns a proper response in Postman but MvcResult returns "application/json;charset=UTF-8" as a response. I tried different solutions present on Internet but nothing seems to work. Please, help me with this.

I want to extract the key-value pair from the JSON response.

spring test = 5.1.8.RELEASE

Controller

```
@RestController
public class CustAuController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/retrieve_something", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    retrieveSomething(){
    }
}
```

Postman Response

```
{
    "total_count" : 3,
    "data" : {
        "list" : [
                   {
                        ...
                   }
                 ]
  }
}
```

Test Class

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @SpringBootTest(classes = ServiceApplication.class)
 @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
 @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
 class ControllerTest {

@Autowired
WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

MockMvc mockMvc;

public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
    try {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@BeforeAll
void setMockMvc() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Retrieve Something")
@Order(1)
void testRetrieveSomething() throws Exception{
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
            "/retrieve_something"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

    System.out.println(    
    result.getResponse().getContentType()); // returns application/json;charset=UTF-8
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change in the last line `getContentType()` to `getContentAsString()`

Comment: I tried that too but getContentAsString() gives no response and says can't act on the null result. But, actually following code works.

    mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(result))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("total_count").isNumber())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

Only thing is that I can't get the content from JSON response. I think there is some problem with application/json;charset=UTF-8" type.

Comment: What is the problem with  application/json;charset=UTF-8, which type are you expecting?

Comment: My Spring Boot version is 2.1.6.RELEASE. Which version are you using?. Don't know if this is a version issue or something.

Comment: I tried it with 2.1.6.REALEASE yet and it also works

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm doing something wrong then, I'll try. Thanks, for your efforts.